# Assossiation in war files

Tags: archive

Working with .war files. The files were associated with the `Archive Manager`. However, I installed a tool called `Astah professional`. Now .war files are associated with `Astah`. How can I change this behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change any file association by right-clicking the file and selecting Properties. In the emerging dialog go to "Open with...", select the desired association and make it default.

Comment: I've done it, it opens with the Archive Manager, but the icon and his options when I right-click are not the Archive.

Comment: @MarkKirby Currently I can only make in my own system which is not English.

Comment: Fair enough....;